# Seg fault when using Botan

Tags: c++, botan

I'm just getting started with Botan. I have included the `botan_all.h` in my code file and am linking to the `libbotan-2.a` library when building.

Here is the relevant part of main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "botan_all.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<uint8_t> key = Botan::hex_decode("2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C");
    std::unique_ptr<Botan::Cipher_Mode> enc = Botan::Cipher_Mode::create("AES-128/CBC/PKCS7", Botan::ENCRYPTION);    
    enc->set_key(key);
}
```

The `enc->set_key(key)` causes a seg fault. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by your Botan version not being build with support for the specified algorithm.  The method `CipherMode::create` returns a `nullptr` if the specified algorithm is not found ([reference](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Cipher__Mode.html#a38e96f53d3e16ea67a0880c010c3ff14)). You would then have to check the result, e.g.:

```
    if (enc == nullptr) {
      throw std::runtime_error{"Cipher not supported!"};
    }
```

Alternatively, you could use `CipherMode::create_or_throw` ([reference](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Cipher__Mode.html#ab906ea0ebf6b31d7722dff72cda85a6e)):

```
Botan::Cipher_Mode::create_or_throw("AES-128/CBC/PKCS7", Botan::ENCRYPTION);
```

You can also check your Botan headers for support for these specific algorithms, by checking if `BOTAN_HAS_AES` and `BOTAN_HAS_MODE_CBC` are defined. If these are not available, you would have to ensure that when you compile botan, you include AES and CBC support, e.g. with:

```
./configure.py --enable-modules=aes,cbc,...
```